# Confirm pending photo tags created with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api

I'm creating an app that tags photos in a fan page. The application adds tags to the photos, but they show up as pending. After each tag "(requested tag)" is shown regardless of rather it's a user tag, or a text tag. When I hover tag, the pop up text says "Tag request sent (Remove Tag)" Even when I login as the tagged user, or the page admin I dont see an option to accept the tag. I can't find any documentation this topic, and have not been able to come up with a solution.

I need to be able to search these tags with FQL, but pending tags do not show up in the quires. How do I confirm these tags after they have been added?

Comment: Any news on this problem? I'm facing the same thing...